# Can a guest share the same network connection as its host?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, proxy, virtualization

Hi Guys i´m a 100% newbie so please be kind :D

I want to run a Ubuntu machine on a Virtual Box Windows Host. I´m currently 
in a company which only allows Windows hosts in their network.

Is it possible to give Ubuntu full internet access and let it appear as my
host machine, so the proxy won´t block its traffic.

I only have access to the host system

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I *think* this is what the default NAT network adapter does. Your guest will not get its own IP but communicate through the host's address. I don't know what result a port scan or something else to detect the OS on the host would result in though.

Comment: Thanks, already tried that but I wasn´t sure if it would appear as a own device.  Let give it a shot and hope i won´t get a nasty Mail from my supervisor ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is your proxy configured in the browser ?
If so you can use Bridge mode and configure the proxy on the browser. If not you can use the NAT mode that will make the traffic goes from your VM to your Windows machine then to the internet.
Here there's a link of how to do it:

https://www.pythian.com/blog/test-lab-using-virtualbox-nat-networking/

Comment: If you set up a bridged network adapter, the guest machine will get its own IP and appear as separate computer in the network, which is the exact opposite of what the question asks for. And what does all this have to do with browser proxies?

Comment: It does that the: I'm 100% newbie might mean that he doesn't really need to have it on nat and he could just use the proxy setting on the browser to have internet.